# custom tablesorter parser causing tablesorter to only sort in one direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I have seen several other people with problems with tablesorter only sorting in one direction, but none of their solutions worked for me as their problems weren't exactly the same as mine.

My tablesorter was working perfectly until I added a custom parser. Below is the code for my custom parser:

```
// add parser through the tablesorter addParser method 
$.tablesorter.addParser({ 
    // set a unique id 
    id: 'weeks', 
    is: function(s) { 
        // return false so this parser is not auto detected 
        return false; 
    }, 
    format: function(s) { 
        // format your data for normalization 
        return s.toLowerCase().replace(/bowl/,100); // replace with 100 since it will be higher than any other week number
    }, 
    // set type, either numeric or text 
    type: 'numeric'
}); 

$(function() { 
    $("#gamehisttab").tablesorter({ 
        headers: { 
            0: { 
                sorter:'weeks'
            } 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

It is very simple, the column of data I am sorting is simply a list of numbers, with some of the cells filled in the with the word 'bowl'. I want the list to sort the numbers in numerical order, and then put all of the 'bowl' cells after the numbers. I replace 'bowl' with 100 because the numbers in question will never be more than 99.

For whatever reason, when I add in the code above, my table loads correctly, and sorts correctly in the descending direction the first time I sort it. However, when I try to sort it a second time (in the ascending direction), it seems to work for a split second but then instantly sorts again back into the descending direction, and after that it will not sort at all, but will just stay in the descending direction when I click the header.

Removing the custom parser results in the tablesorter working correctly again (although obviously not sorting in the custom way that I want).

I am very confused by this problem and cannot figure out a solution. If you need any other parts of my code, I would be glad to post them.

Thank you so much for any help you can give me!

Comment: Would you happen to be using my fork of tablesorter? If so, you can set the [`stringTo` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#stringto) to `"bottom"` to always keep the "bowl" cells at the bottom of the table. If you aren't using my fork, then could you please share a demo of your code, it would make it easier to troubleshoot the problem.